# How can I convert below sql to Querydsl code?(querydsl oracle hierarchical query, level, lpad)

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data, querydsl

How can I convert the below sql to `Querydsl` code?

(querydsl oracle hierarchical query, level, lpad)

```
select lpad(' ',(level-1)*2,' ') || ename, sal, deptno
  from emp
start with ename = 'KING'
connect by prior empno = mgr
```

Result:

```
KING    5000    10
  JONES   2975    20
    SCOTT   3000    20
      ADAMS   1100    20
    FORD    3000    20
      SMITH   800     20
  BLAKE   2850    30
    ALLEN   1600    30
    WARD    1250    30
    MARTIN  1250    30
    TURNER  1500    30
    JAMES   950     30
  CLARK   2450    10
```

Comment: START WITH ... CONNECT BY is Oracle's venerable syntax for hierarchical queries,  Eventually standardised SQL came up with a mechanism to do the same, the recursive WITH clause.  QueryDSL supports [recursive WITH clauses](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/844).

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

It is supported, see `com.querydsl.sql.oracle.OracleQuery` (http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.7/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/oracle/OracleQuery.html)

```
import com.querydsl.sql.oracle.OracleGrammar;
import com.querydsl.sql.oracle.OracleQuery;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*
//...
OracleQuery query = new OracleQuery(getConnection(), config);
query.select(StringExpressions.lpad(
    Expressions.stringTemplate("' '").stringValue(), 
    OracleGrammar.level.subtract(1).multiply(2), ' ')       
    .concat(emp.ename), 
    emp.sal, emp.deptno)   
.startWith(emp.ename.eq("KING"))   
.connectBy(emp.empno.eq(emp.mgr))    
.from(emp);
```